# Adding image in awt

Tags: java, image, awt, graphics2d

I was trying to add an image in one of GridBagLayout cells. But i am not able to achieve it.

```
  public class imageInAwt extends Applet{
     Panel p;
     BufferedImage img;
     public void init(){
     setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
     GridBagConstraints gbc =new GridBagConstraints();
     gbc.gridx = 0;
     gbc.gridy = 0;
     try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("settings.gif"));
     } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     add(new junaid(img),gbc);
     gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
     add(new Label("Junaid"),gbc);
     } 
}

    class junaid extends Canvas {
        Image img;
        public junaid(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
        }
        public void paint (Graphics g) {
            BufferedImage image = null;
                g.drawImage(image, 2, 3, null);
                g.drawString("Junaid", 22, 16);
        }
        public void setImage (Image img){
        this.img = img;
        }
    }
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the location and content of the HTML, & the location of the image?  Is the applet available for us to visit?  At what address/URL?

Comment: Where the applet class is located?

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        BufferedImage image = null;
            g.drawImage(image, 2, 3, null);
            g.drawString("Junaid", 22, 16);
    }
```

Huh?!?

```
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(img, 2, 3, this);
            g.drawString("Junaid", 22, 16);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Applet.getImage()` method of the Applet class.

```
Image img=getImage(getCodeBase(),"settings.gif");
```

Comment: Still didnt work, my image is in res folder. i also tried changing the path of image that is    Image img=getImage(getCodeBase(),"res/settings.gif");